# How to check if a string is hashed by Laravel Hash?

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5, bcrypt

In my project using `Laravel 5.1`, beside Hash default class, I also used my library to hash password. So how can I check a string be hashed by `Laravel` Hash or not ?
Example :

```
$2y$10$ug8B6Pxs546eQBNICxsEOOH3NgpXjOIo.g4rf1FPZk2xJncWcFUpu
```

Comment: Maybe try-catch decrypt it, and if it fails, it's not?

Comment: Which kind of encryption does this library do? Is it one-way encryption like another hashing function or two-way as it is decryptable? If it is another one-way encryption i guess you are out of luck. If it is decryptable, you can try decrypting all the hashes and see if you get exceptions. The ones that give exceptions will most probably be the default Laravel hashes

Comment: @Martins.A - see `hash_password` it's standard these days.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix nice, did not know about this characteristic of BCRYPT algorithm of always having the $2y$ id. Guess the OP is lucky then, unless the second algorithm is the same and also has the id!

Comment: Yea I'm not sure it's necessarily part of bcrypt or the hash_password function.   It may be a algorithm identifier for the password function.  I'm not sure.  But hashes are typically one way encryption and always the same length, such as md5 is 32 sha1 is 40 and sha256 is 60.  Usually it's enough to simply test for the length.

Comment: Also found [this answer](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/20543) explaining more about the BCRYPT id variants.

Comment: @Martins.A  - nice I always used to use sha512 and salting in mine but I haven't written one in like 4 or 5 years now ... lol ... The platform we use now uses the `hash_pasword` so the next one I make will use that.

Answer (score 14):

You can check the lenght

```
if( strlen($hash) == 60 )
```

> PASSWORD_BCRYPT - Use the CRYPT_BLOWFISH algorithm to create the hash.
>   This will produce a standard crypt() compatible hash using the "$2y$"
>   identifier. The result will always be a 60 character string, or FALSE
>   on failure.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

In addition you could check for the   $2y$ identifier.  with a regx like this

```
  preg_match('/^\$2y\$/', $hash );
```

Or even with `strpos($hash, '$2y$')`  although I am not sure what offset it would give off the top of my head.

So for example

```
 $hash = '$2y$10$ug8B6Pxs546eQBNICxsEOOH3NgpXjOIo.g4rf1FPZk2xJncWcFUpu';

 if( strlen($hash) == 60 && preg_match('/^\$2y\$/', $hash ))
```

You can be pretty confident that if it starts with `$2y$` and is 60 in length then it's hashed.  There may be a non-zero chance you would run into something that would be like that, but it's practically nill.

Comment: `strpos($hash, '$2y$') === 0` :)

Comment: I needed this to pass a test with passwords that weren't hashed. Thanks.

Comment: Do not always start with "$2y", I use Laravel 10 and my hash start wiith "$2a".
I think better to use Hash::needsRehash :
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/hashing#determining-if-a-password-needs-to-be-rehashed

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of Laravel, you can use `Hash::info(...)`. When `algo` key is `null` or `algoName` is `"unknown"`, then it is not hashed:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

Hash::info('Non Hashed String');
//= [
//    "algo" => null,
//    "algoName" => "unknown",
//    "options" => [],
//   ]

Hash::info('$2y$10$HUaJYd/zq.V8DKPXMQPzPuICfdm1uqvASgnBc9Ri4nnvmp/PDuE22');
//= [
//    "algo" => "2y",
//    "algoName" => "bcrypt",
//    "options" => [
//      "cost" => 10,
//    ],
//  ]
```

Note: In Laravel 5.8 `algo` is `0` instead of `null`.

So, you can use `!Hash::info($value)['algo'];`:

```php
$isNotHashed = !Hash::info($value)['algo'];

// Or
$isNotHashed = Hash::info($value)['algoName'] === 'unknown';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Hash::needsRehash($input)` method to check if an string hashed or nor.